# codeigniter match number in string

Tags: php, codeigniter, numbers

Using codeigniter active records method, i want to find out which rows contains the id=6.
Pls advise.

```
$this->db->like('id', 6);  
$this->db->get('mytable');  

   | id       |
---+----------+---
   | 3,16,8,6 |
---+----------+---
   | 6,66     |
---+----------+---
   | 7,560    |
---+----------+---
```

Comment: Are you trying to match only the 6, or match 66 and 560 as well?

Comment: i want only the id=6.

Comment: The way your data is structured makes this difficult to achieve without some reasonably complex SQL. Without knowing more about your table structure, I can assume that those IDs are mapping to some other table, and you should instead have a table in the middle (between this current table and the table that those IDs refer to) which has a record for each, mapping the relationship. The other alternative is to select all records that have a 6 in the field, then loop through them with PHP to decide which ones are actually valid using `if(in_array( 6, explode(',', $ids) )) { /* do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `FIND_IN_SET`, like:

```
$searchterm = 6;
$where = "FIND_IN_SET('".$searchterm."', id)";  
$this->db->where( $where );
$this->db->get('mytable');
```